# How to select a cell content from a DataGridView ? (C#)

Tags: c#

I want to add a image from a ComboBox, but ComboBox has got only the image name.
In a DataGridView there are two cells.  Cell01 for the image name, Cell02 for the image file path.
When I selected a name form the ComboBox i want create a variable for add its correct file path form the DataGridView. What is the code for identify the correct file path for selected image name..?

"This below code will work only when adding images from same Location..  "

```
string imagename = cmbDataGridLink.SelectedItem.ToString();
int selectedRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
string filepath = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
string path = filepath + imagename;
picbComboBox.Image = Image.FromFile(path);
```

Comment: I see you are already getting the path; what's the issue after you've done so?  is it not returning a `string` or is the path incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've already got most of what you're looking for.  Assuming that you are just trying to listen for cell selected events you could try something like setting up an event listener on the `DataGridView` for when the selection is changed by user and execute your code there:

//Create a custom listener for `SelectionChanged` on the `DataGridView` :

    `private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string imagename = cmbDataGridLink.SelectedItem.ToString();
        int selectedRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        string filepath = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        string path = filepath + imagename;
        picbComboBox.Image = Image.FromFile(path);
    }`

//then add the listener to your `DataGridView` when `Window` or app loads:

        `DataGridView1.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(
            DataGridView1_SelectionChanged);`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8

EDIT: after re-reading the question I am extremely confused about what you want.  If you want to get the selection of the `ComboBox` index changed event then use this code:

//Create a custom listener for `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` on the `ComboBox` :

    `private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string imagename = cmbDataGridLink.SelectedItem.ToString();
        int selectedRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        string filepath = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedRow].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        string path = filepath + imagename;
        picbComboBox.Image = Image.FromFile(path);
    }`

//then add the listener to your `ComboBox` when `Window` or app loads:

`ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += 
            new System.EventHandler(ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thanks a lot bro.. !! I will try this. Also i want to say sorry if  something wrong in my question, I'm just a beginner in programming..

Comment: yeah no worries; I hope it helps